# I can't read values from memory

Tags: c++

So i am trying to get read some values from a game. I can successfully read the data from game via Cheat Engine. But when i try to enter the value to my code and receive values i only get 0. However when i try to do the same thing with some other programs it works without a problem. Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

DWORD pid;
DWORD adr = 0x23CAE074AA8;
int my_value;

int main(){

    HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(0, ("game"));

    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);
    std::cout << pid << std::endl;
    HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
    while(1){
        ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)adr, &my_value, sizeof(my_value),0);
        std::cout << my_value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I think the problem is the length of my address. Other programs  adresses had shorter length. It also gives these errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]  read_memory.cpp /read_memory/src    line 17 C/C++ Problem
```

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
overflow in conversion from 'long long int' to 'LONG' {aka 'long int'} changes value from '2459641006760' to '-1375253848' [-Woverflow] read_memory.cpp /read_memory/src    line 6  C/C++ Problem
```

Comment: the error tels you what your problem is - because you have overflow you are reading the wrong address in memory, try use long long int insted of long

Comment: I am still geting zeros

Comment: `DWORD adr = 0x23CAE074AA8;` - You can't expect addresses of stuff to be stable across multiple invocations of a program in these days of ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization).

Comment: Yes i can read the exact same Addres in Cheat Engine. What should i do. Btw im a beginner in c++

Comment: ***Btw im a beginner in c++*** Modern games are designed to require a higher level of understanding to defeat the protections.

Comment: I am just trying to read some values

Comment: The address will change each time you run it unless you disable ASLR in your operating system.

Answer (score 2):

As the message says, `DWORD` seems too small to store addresses in your environment.

You should use `uintptr_t` from the header `cstdint` to store integers to be used as pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint> // add this

DWORD pid;
uintptr_t adr = 0x23CAE074AA8; // change type

// ...
```

Comment: Even i place my address directly like this ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)0x22349071B78, &my_value, sizeof(my_value),0); it still doesnt work.